# wrapping selected nth childs in divs using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I am trying to select divs and wrap them in bootstrap columns using the nth child.

I have:

```
<div class="owl-news">
    <div class="item news-v2">
    <div class="item news-v2">
    <div class="item news-v2">
    <div class="item news-v2">
    <div class="item news-v2">
    <div class="item news-v2">
    <div class="item news-v2">
    <div class="item news-v2">
</div>
```

At the moment I have tried (as the divs have the class 'news-v2'):

```
var divs = $(".owl-news > .news-v2");
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=3) {
    divs.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<div class='col-md-2'></div>");
}
```

which gives the following output:

```
 <div class="owl-news">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="item news-v2">
        <div class="item news-v2">
        <div class="item news-v2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="item news-v2">
        <div class="item news-v2">
        <div class="item news-v2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="item news-v2">
        <div class="item news-v2">
    </div>
    </div>
```

But this just wraps every 3 divs in col-md-2 and i need to specifically select the first div, the next 2, the next 2 and the last 3. To produce what I would like:

```
<div class="owl-news">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="item news-v2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="item news-v2"></div>
        <div class="item news-v2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="item news-v2"></div>
        <div class="item news-v2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="item news-v2"></div>
        <div class="item news-v2"></div>
        <div class="item news-v2"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Best if you're not lazy. Instead of showing `<div 4>` etc. actually show what they look like. And also write out your final html result.

Comment: I thought the numbering would help understanding with what I wanted, but fair enough, I have updated the question.

Comment: So the `I want` is the final result? And `which gives the following output` is what your current output is from your code? What does the starting code look like? Generally I think it's best to describe your problem in this order. `What I started with` -> `what I did (and the output)` -> `what I want`.

Comment: @A.Lau thank you for you advice, i have updated the question accordingly. Hope this helps

Comment: Ah looks much better, now your problem will be much more appealing to a larger audience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, unfortunately, since the format you want doesn't really follow any pattern, you kind of have make an arbitrary selection.

See my code below.

```js
var divs = $(".owl-news > .news-v2");
let array = [
  { length: 1, num: 4 },
  { length: 2, num: 3 },
  { length: 2, num: 3 },
  { length: 3, num: 2 }  
];

let i = 0;


for (let item of array) {
  divs.slice(i, i+item.length).wrapAll(`<div class='col-md-${item.num}'></div>`);
  i += item.length;
}

console.log($(".owl-news").html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="owl-news">
    <div class="item news-v2"></div>
    <div class="item news-v2"></div>
    <div class="item news-v2"></div>
    <div class="item news-v2"></div>
    <div class="item news-v2"></div>
    <div class="item news-v2"></div>
    <div class="item news-v2"></div>
    <div class="item news-v2"></div>
</div>
```

The reason why your code doesn't work is because you're always adding 3 `divs.slice(i, i+3)` and always using using "md-2" `.wrapAll("<div class='col-md-2'></div>");`